# string conversion to hours and minutes (not pandas standard time)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Lets say for e.g., I have (series) data in string format (e.g., '225586:47'). I want the machine to understand that this denotes hours and minutes.

Any idea how achieve this?

Comment: "I want the machine to understand that this denotes hours and minutes." what, *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: What would you expect the output to be?  Two series with one as hours as an integer and another as minutes as an integer?  Maybe return the number of minutes (hours*60 + minutes), as an integer?  Maybe return a series of hours as a float (hours + minutes/60)?

Comment: I want to do a sum of all the elements of the series. The data is currently in str format and therefore cannot be added.

Comment: And return what?  A string in the original format of "HH:MM"?  Or maybe a float?

Comment: @Tanmoy Well, which numbers *should* be added?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

#this function will split a string, and treat each part as a part of a time
#then return seconds as an integer
def get_secs(time_str): #assumes string is in format HH:MM
    h, m = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 #convert everything into seconds

#This function will take seconds and convert into a string
#in the format of "HH:MM"
#Note that if there are fractions of a minute, these will be rounded down to make MM an integer
def get_hhmm(secs):
    hours = secs / (3600) #get the hours from seconds
    minutes = (hours - int(hours)) * (60) # remainder as minutes
    return "%02i:%02i" % (hours, minutes) #we have to integer-ize both of these since they are each floats

#dummy series
s = pd.Series(['10:20', '20:30', '30:40', '40:50', '50:60'])

#apply this function to the elements of your series
s = s.apply(get_secs)
#sum them
sum(s) #as seconds
sum(s)/60 #as minutes
sum(s)/60/60 #as hours
print(get_hhmm(sum(s))) #as an "hh:mm" string
```

Answer (score 0):

I split the string based on the ":", took the first part, converted it to integer and multiplied it by 60. Took the second part, converted it to integer and added to the product that I got from the first part.

Did this for the entire column, added the values, divided by 60 to get hours and minutes.